# Laurent Series around $z_0=0$ and $z_0=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, partial-fractions

I tried to expand three functions in Laurent series, but I don't have any given answer for them and I'm not very confident that what I'm doing is correct.

The first one is $f(z)=\frac{z^3e^{1/z}}{z+1}$ around $z_0 = 0$ and this is how I attempted to expand it:

$$f(z)=z^3e^{1/z}\frac{1}{1-(-z)}=z^3 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{-n}}{n!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} z^n =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^3}{n!}$$

The second one is $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$ around $z_0=1$ and the region is the whole complex plane. First I rewrote the functions using partial fractions and did some manipulation $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{z}{2})}\bigg)$ and then:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}\bigg]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n-1}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\bigg)$$

The third one had me baffled.. $f(z)=\frac{e-e^z}{z(z-1)^2}$ around $z_0=1$ and in the region $0<|z-1|<1$. I tried the following:

$$f(z)=\frac{e}{z(z-1)^2}-\frac{1}{z(z-1)^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e(z-1)^n}{n!}=-\frac{e}{z(z-1)^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}=-\frac{e}{z}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(z-1)^{n-2}}{n!}$$

Could any of these answers be considered correct? If not, what is the correct way to approach these problems?

Comment: Where does the equality$$z^3 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{-n}}{n!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} z^n =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^3}{n!}$$come from?

Comment: I'm bringing everything into a single sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{3-n+n}}{n!}$$ Is it wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are claiming that$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n.$$Am I right?

Comment: I thought the $z$'s were the same in the sums. Why should they not be the same?

Comment: Let me ask you another question then. Are you claiming that$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{-n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n?$$

Comment: I understand what you mean, what I wrote down is wrong. But how do I go about compactifying 
$$z^3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{-n}}{n!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n z^n$$ into a single sum?

Comment: It is equal to$$\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{3-m+n}}{m!}.$$

Comment: What happened to the $(-1)^n$ factor? I don't understand

Comment: I forgot about it! Sorry. It should be$$\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{3-m+n}}{m!}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and input. One last question - are the solutions to the other 2 functions I attempted to expand correct?

Comment: The answer to the second one makes no sense, since it is centered around $0$ rather than $1$. Anyway, asking for a Laurent series defined in “the whole complex plane” makes no sense.

Comment: The answer to the third one also makes no sense. You wrote$$-\frac{e}{z}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(z-1)^{n-2}}{n!}$$. What is that $\frac ez$ doing there?

Comment: For the first, I suggest rewriting it as $f(z) = z^2\frac{e^{1/z}}{1+\frac 1z}$, then finding the Taylor series for $g(w) = \frac{e^w}{1+w}$ about $0$, substituting $w = z^{-1}$ and multiplying by $z^2$. For the second, make the substitution $w = z-1$, find the Taylor series at $0$ for $wf(w)$, and dividing it by $w$, then replacing $w$ with $z-1$. Similarly for the third, except you will need the taylor series for $w^2f(w)$. and divide it by $w^2$.